# Running bin file in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to build a bash script that runs a bin file.
However the question is:
how to continue the script even after bin operation is completed to perform other commands?

Comment: have you tried it ? because after .bin file has finished its work remaining bash script will execute with out any problems .

Comment: Yep,I have.
I was installing jdk through this script.
Had it installed though,just trying out some scripting.
Gave the permissions, ran the bin file and the last option I saw was ENTER,after that it returned to the prompt.

Comment: ah..found it.there was a script error.ty